# How would i replicate this curl GET request with --data-urlencode on postman

Tags: postman

How do i add `--data-urlencode` parameter to postman as that is my main issue.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

1. Provide -H values in Headers
2. Use below GET url

   [https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}](https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where=%7B%22playerName%22:%22Sean%20Plott%22,%22cheatMode%22:false%7D)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this question when I was trying to convert a `POST` request with `--data-urlencode` which worked in `cURL` but gave `500` in Postman. I will leave the solution here as other might find this question.

Turned out that curl is sending the `POST` request with `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the header when using `--data-urlencode`. On the other hand Postman will only set this header if you add the query parameters at the Body tab, but won't set any content-type when using the Params tab. As occasional Postman user you would probably go with the Params tab as that comes natural for query parameters.

So you either use the Body tab to define parameters, or you set the content-type header manually.